# No sun in apartment, options for seedlings/propagation?

Tags: germination, seedlings, greenhouse

I have roof apartment with northfacing windows and southfacing terrace. Unfortunatley, there is no windowstill on the windows, and roof angle means that any particular spot on the floor has direct sunlight only about 2-3 hours a day.
Trying to come up with a solution for seedlings propagation indoors and i only see two options -grow light or mini-greenhouse on southfacing terrace. Avg outdoor temps in my area are - 4c in Feb and 9c in March. Will greenhouse even work with that ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of plants you want to propagate or germinate. Most plants, even cacti don't need direct sunlight for germination or propagation. However, when passed the seedling stage they will need direct sunlight, so for the long term a greenhouse with direct sunlight would be a great idea. In winter, when it is too cold you'll have to get your plants inside. The plants will be in dormant stage so the low light levels are in wintertime no problem.

But also for indoors, where there is hardly any direct sunlight there are houseplants that can be grown at the north facing window. Think of *Dracaena* or *Sansevieria* just to name a few.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I forgot to mention I thinking mostly about tomatoes and herbs. Tomatoes needs to be kept indoors at least untill may in my climate.

Comment: Okay tomatoes can be sown 6-8 weeks before putting them outside, so if May (half May?) would be safe, start sowing 6-8 weeks before that. However, tomatoes seedlings also need light (like a south facing window sill), so I expect in your situation they would become long and leggy. You could try LED grow lights, I have bought some via eBay directly from China, they are not expensive there (maybe a few dollars). And put them outside on the terrace in May.